# Regarding removing elements from an ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have two `Arraylists` defined as shown below. The first `ArrayList` `List-1`is populated with `Integers` from 0-10, and the second `ArrayList` `List_2` is populated with the first four elemnts contained in the `ArrayList`List_1`.

what I am trying to do is, after populating  the second `ArrayList` `List_2` with the first four elements contained in the first `ArrayList` `List_1`, i want to delete/remove the first four elements from `List_1` as they are copied in the `List_2`.

But when I run the code posted below, I found that not the first four consecutive elements are removed from `List_1` despite I used a `for-loop` iterates from 0-3 and remove the elements from `List_1` at position 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

JavaCode:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        list_1.add(i);
        System.out.println("list_1 contains: "+list_1.get(i));
    }

    populateList(list_2, list_1);

    for (int i=0; i<list_2.size(); i++)
        System.out.println("list_2 contains: "+list_2.get(i));

    for (int i=0; i<list_1.size(); i++)
        System.out.println("list_1 contains: "+list_1.get(i));

}

private static void populateList(List<Integer> list_22, List<Integer> list_12) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        list_22.add(list_12.get(i));

    for (int i=0;  i<4; i++)
        list_12.remove(i);
}
```

Comment: Don't remove elements like this! Use an iterator.

Comment: @MarounMaroun can you provide some examples

Comment: @TimB already provided one, see his answer.

Comment: Why use an iterator instead? I always get `ConcurrentModificationException` from it so I don't like it, personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for (int i=0;  i<4; i++)
    list_12.remove(i);
```

if you have list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` for example, and you remove first element (at index 0) you will have `[2,3,4]` and *then* if you remove second element from *that* list (at index 1) you will have `[2,4]`. So change that loop to:

```
for (int i=0;  i<4; i++)
    list_12.remove(0);
```

(Also note that removing elements from start of `ArrayList` is costly since all other elements needs to shift.)

Answer (score 2):

You are removing elements 0, 1, 2, 3 - but each time from the list the other one was removed from.

i.e.

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Remove 0:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Remove 1:

1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Remove 2:

1,3,5,6,7,8,9

etc

To do what you want loop from 3 to 0 instead of 0 to 3 or use an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Make `list_12.remove(0);` in for-loop

**i.e.**

```
private static void populateList(List<Integer> list_22, List<Integer> list_12) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        list_22.add(list_12.get(i));

    for (int i=0;  i<4; i++)
        list_12.remove(0); //Make it as 0
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Iterator<Interger>`? Also `while(itr.hasNext())` would remove all elements, OP wants to remove only 4.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove an element from an ArrayList, the indices all get pushed back by one.
The indices go from 0...9 to 0...8 to 0...7 and so on.

So instead of

```
for (int i=0;  i<4; i++)
    list_12.remove(i);
```

What would work in this specific case is

```
for (int i=0;  i<4; i++)
    list_12.remove(0);
```

What I tend to use is

```
for (int i = 0; i < list_12.size(); i++)
{
    list_12.remove(i--);
}
```

Assuming there is other code, and the removal of elements is conditional.

If you really just have to clear out all the elements, you can use the `clear()` function.

Or maybe something like,

```
while(list_12.size() > 0)
{
    list_12.remove(0);
}
```

Either works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
list_12.removeAll(list22);
```

that remove from list12 all elements that are contained in list22

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use [subList() method from List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29). This method returns a portion of the list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.

Then your program would look like this

```
populateWithIntegers();
populateWithFirtsFourElements();
removeFirstFourElements();

private void populateWithIntegers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list_1.add(i);
        System.out.println("list_1 contains: " + list_1.get(i));
    }
}

private void populateWithFirtsFourElements() {
    list_2 = list_1.subList(0, 4);
}

private void removeFirstFourElements() {
    list_1 = list_1.subList(4, list_1.size());
}
```

The result is:

```
List 1: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
List 2: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```